# Match mixture of characters and digits in Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to extract substrings from a pandas df, and place them into a new column.
The strings I have look like:

```
hj_yu_fb824_as22
jk_yu_fb638
```

I need to extract:

```
 fb824
 fb638
```

Moreover, they substring can be in two separate columns of the dataframe (altough appearing only once), because the df looks looks like:

```
col1                col2
mf_lp_gn817_ml46    d_nb_05340.gif 
desktop_300x250_mf  mf_lp_fb824_ml46.html 
desktop_300x250_mf  dd_lp_ig805.html 
desktop_728x90_mf   mf_lp_fb824_ml46.html
```

I would like to obtain something like:

```
col1                col2                     col3
mf_lp_gn817_ml46    d_nb_05340.gif           gn817
desktop_300x250_mf  mf_lp_fb824_ml46.html    fb824
desktop_300x250_mf  dd_lp_ig805.html         ig805
desktop_728x90_mf   mf_lp_fb824_ml46.html    fb824
```

So the substring looks like:

1) two lower case characters at the beginning, followed by 3 digits
2) between two '*' or with just one '*', or between '_' and '.' something else

I came up with:

```
 \_([^()]*)\_
```

But it just matches anything between the "_"s regardless of the pattern described above.

And moreover, how efficiently apply a regex to a pandas dataframe?

Here's the reproducible dataframe:

```
df = DataFrame({'col1': {0: 'mf_lp_gn817_ml46',
 1: 'desktop_300x250_mf',
 2: 'desktop_300x250_mf',
 3: 'desktop_728x90_mf'},
 'col2': {0: 'd_nb_05340.gif ',
 1: 'mf_lp_fb824_ml46.html ',
 2: 'dd_lp_ig805.html ',
 3: 'mf_lp_fb824_ml46.html '},
 'col3': {0: 'gn817', 1: 'fb824', 2: 'ig805', 3: 'fb824'}})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are possibly more input strings necessary but for your above strings you could come up with the following regex:

```
_([a-z]{2}[0-9]{3})[_.]
# this is an underscore
# followed by exactly 2 letters and 3 digits
# followed by an underscore or a dot
# the whole match is captured to group1
```

For your above strings this would be:

```
mf_lp_gn817_ml46    d_nb_05340.gif           -> gn817
desktop_300x250_mf  mf_lp_fb824_ml46.html    -> fb824
desktop_300x250_mf  dd_lp_ig805.html         -> ig805
desktop_728x90_mf   mf_lp_fb824_ml46.html    -> fb824
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iQ0eU9/3).

### Python Code:

To apply this to your DataFrame, see the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import re

df = DataFrame({'col1': {0: 'mf_lp_gn817_ml46',
 1: 'desktop_300x250_mf',
 2: 'desktop_300x250_mf',
 3: 'desktop_728x90_mf'},
 'col2': {0: 'd_nb_05340.gif ',
 1: 'mf_lp_fb824_ml46.html ',
 2: 'dd_lp_ig805.html ',
 3: 'mf_lp_fb824_ml46.html '}})

regex = r'_([a-z]{2}[0-9]{3})[_.]'
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for column in row.keys():
        m = re.search(regex, row[column])
        if m is not None:
            df.ix[index, 'col3'] = m.group(1)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need! but, how to apply it on both columns and grab the result in the 3rd column only when its found?

Comment: @xxxvinxxx: See the updated answer, tested with jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I learnt a lot from https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231450/jan 's answer, very elegant. I also came across this extra step and thought I'd contribute.

saving the resulting regular expression object for reuse is more efficient (if you are doing more than a few).
see: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html 6.2.2. Module Contents

```
prog = re.compile(r'_([a-z]{2}[0-9]{3})[_.]')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for column in row.keys():
        m = prog.search(row[column])
        if m is not None:
            df.ix[index, 'col3'] = m.group(1)
```

Comment: I'm still a bit puzzled how m.group(1) ends up losing the underscores at the start and end.